# Search Type array

Tags: c#, arrays, types

I have such array

```
private Type[] _excludeExceptions;
```

I would like to search it and find is searched type exist in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, how about using `Contains`:

```
bool x = _excludeExceptions.Contains(typeToFind);
```

Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool Excluded(Type t)
{
  foreach(var type in _excludeExceptions)
  {
    if(type.Equals(t))
      return true;
  }
}
```

You could also use linq if .Net 3.5 or above:

```
return _excludeExceptions.Any(type => type.Equals(t));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool typexists = _excludeExceptions.Contains(tpyeof(sometype));
```